# Is there any online tool to design HTML web pages?

Tags: html, jsp

I have been looking for an online tool to work with html/JSP web pages.

Comment: Questions asking for tool or service recommendations are [not germane to stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need online tool if you can simply use windows notepad? If you aren't introduced to the programming of html, use w3schools to learn. Perhaps if you need an online article/blog, people commonly use blogger.com or wordpress (just search it on google)